# 16-Bit addition of 2n Scaled Integer

Tags: c, math, autosar

When I going to implement 16-Bit addition of 2n Scaled Integer from autosar specification. I didn't get what is a, b  and c values in these.

I am going to implement 16-Bit addition of 2n Scaled Integer from autosar specification for mfx modules. in which I get in 8.6.4.1 16-Bit Addition of 2n Scaled Integer in which they specify 
a Radix point position of the first fixed point operand. Must be a constant expression.
b Radix point position of the second fixed point operand. Must be a constant expression.
c Radix point position of the fixed point result. Must be a constant expression.

Valid range: 0 ≤ |a - b| ≤ 15
(c - b) ≤ 15, (a - c) ≤ 15, a ≥ b
(c - a) ≤ 15, (b - c) ≤ 15, a < b

But I don't understand How will I get the range value for c.

for below condition

```
 #include "stdio.h"
  void main()
  {
    if(a > =b)
    C = 2^(c-a) * [x + (y * 2^(a-b))]
    else

    C = 2^(c-b) * [(x * 2^(b-a)) + y].
  }
```

What will be the ans if x =10, y=10, and a=20, b=10, and c= 100;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem converting a maths equation to C source code. Please note that in maths, 2^n means raise 2 to the power n.  Thus m*2^n means m*2^abs(n) if n >=0, and means m/(2^abs(n)) if n < 0.

Thus, reading the [spec, page 53-54](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/4-2/AUTOSAR_SWS_MFXLibrary.pdf), we have for example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t Mfx_AddP2_u16u16_u16(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c)
{
    if(a>=b)
    {
        if(((a-b)>15) || ((c-b)>15) || ((a-c)>15))
        {
          //SWS_Mfx_00154 - saturate to boundary value
          return UINT16_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t baseValue = (UINT32_C(1) << (a-b)) * y + x;
            if(c>=a)
            {
                return (uint16_t)(baseValue << (c-a));
            }
            else
            {
                //SWS_Mfx_00155 - round to zero
                return (uint16_t)(baseValue >> (a-c));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(((b-a)>15) || ((c-a)>15) || ((b-c)>15))
        {
          //SWS_Mfx_00154 - saturate to boundary value
          return UINT16_MAX;
        }
        else
        {
            uint32_t baseValue = (UINT32_C(1) << (b-a)) * x + y;
            if(c>=b)
            {
                return (uint16_t)(baseValue << (c-b));
            }
            else
            {
                //SWS_Mfx_00155 - round to zero
                return (uint16_t)(baseValue >> (b-c));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I trust you can similarly complete the functions declared below:

```
uint16_t Mfx_AddP2_u16s16_u16(uint16_t x,  int16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c);
uint16_t Mfx_AddP2_s16s16_u16( int16_t x,  int16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c);
int16_t  Mfx_AddP2_u16u16_s16(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c);
int16_t  Mfx_AddP2_u16s16_s16(uint16_t x,  int16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c);
int16_t  Mfx_AddP2_s16s16_s16( int16_t x,  int16_t y, int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c);
```

Note: be careful of signed parameters and return values.

---

**Edit: Answering actual question**

Given you ask what the result will be when x =10, y=10, and a=20, b=10, and c= 100;
Check:

1. Is 0<=abs(a-b)<=15 - yes
2. Is a>=b - yes
3. Is (c-b)<=15 - NO

So, in terms of SWS_Mfx_00154, the result must be

1. UINT16_MAX (65535) for Mfx_AddP2_u16u16_u16, Mfx_AddP2_u16s16_u16
   and Mfx_AddP2_s16s16_u16

, 
and

2. INT16_MAX (32767) for Mfx_AddP2_u16u16_s16, Mfx_AddP2_u16s16_s16 and
   Mfx_AddP2_s16s16_s16

Comment: Thanks @ Gunther Schulz. your ans helps me alot, but for 32-Bit to 16-Bit 2n Scaled Integer Conversion

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal, I don't understand your comment, could you rephrase it?

Comment: Thanks @ Gunther Schulz. ur ans helps me alot, but for 32- 16-Bit 2n Conversion I write the code as   is it ok?                                                  
   flaot32 v_Return_val ;          
  sint16  v_ScaleFactor;
  ScaleFactor = c - a;
  if(SCALE_MAX7 < ScaleFactor )
  {
    ScaleFactor = SCALE_MAX7;
  }
  else if(SCALE_MIN15 > ScaleFactor )
  {
    ScaleFactor = ME_SCALE_MIN15;
  }
    v_Return_val = truncf(powf(2.0f,(float32)ScaleFactor ) * (float32)x);
  if(MAX_VAL< v_Return_val_f32) 
  {
    v_Return_val = MAX_VAL;
  }
  return (uint8)v_Return_val ;
}

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal firstly, you are dealing with scaled integers, not floating points - dont use them, they'll introduce rounding errors. Secondly, the exact algorithm is given in the datasheet, and coded accordingly in my answer. Thirdly, my question is with your phrase "32-Bit to 16-Bit 2n Scaled Integer conversion"

Comment: I understand @ Gunther Schulz ,and completely satisfied with ur ans. Thanks A lot:)

Comment: @VikrantDaharwal, its a pleasure. Please pay it forward and upvote and actually accept the answer.